# Child button of Grid Control does not always appear on mouse-over event

Tags: wpf

I'm working with DevExpress WPF controls but this question seems more within the context of straight WPF.

I'm using a DevExpress GridControl and one of the columns contains a WPF grid (**VendorMainGrid**) with a ComboBoxEdit and a SimpleButton (**MainButton**) as child controls, each in it's own grid column.

In addition, the dropdown list of the ComboBoxEdit also has each of its items composed of a Grid (**VendorItemGrid**) with a TextBlock and SimpleButton (**ItemButton**) as child controls, again each in its own grid column.

Both SimpleButtons use a DataTrigger that examines the value of the "**IsMouseOver**" property of the parent Grid, and if the value is True, the Visibility of the SimpleButton is set to **Visible**.

I am trying to create the behavior where the grid child SimpleButton becomes visible on a MouseOver event of **ANY** part of the parent Grid (**VendorMainGrid or VendorItemGrid**).

The behavior I am seeing, however, is that the SimpleButton is only visible when the cursor is over the TextBlock or the ComboBoxEdit. The SimpleButton is a child of its parent Grid, and considering the DataTrigger, I don't understand why the SimpleButton is not visible when the cursor is over it.

The DataTemplate defining this column appears as follows:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="VendorComboColumnTemplate">
        <ContentControl>
            <dxg:GridColumn 
                Binding="{Binding RowData.Row.SelectedVendor, Mode=TwoWay}"
                Header="{Binding Path=(dxci:DependencyObjectExtensions.DataContext).Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                Width="{Binding Path=(dxci:DependencyObjectExtensions.DataContext).Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Name="VendorMainGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <!--The VendorMainGrid ComboBox-->
                            <dxe:ComboBoxEdit
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                IsTextEditable="False"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding RowData.Row.SelectedVendor, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding RowData.Row.VendorList, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                >
                                <dxe:ComboBoxEdit.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="dxe:ComboBoxEditItem">
                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                                    </Style>
                                </dxe:ComboBoxEdit.ItemContainerStyle>

                                <!--The dropdown list item template-->
                                <dxe:ComboBoxEdit.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid Name="VendorItemGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding}" />

                                            <dx:SimpleButton Grid.Column="1" Padding="0" Width="20" Height="20"
                                                Name="ItemButton"
                                                Command="{Binding Path=(dxe:BaseEdit.OwnerEdit).DataContext.RowData.Row.DeleteVendorCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                                >
                                                <dx:SimpleButton.Content>
                                                    <Image Source="{dx:DXImage Image=Delete_16x16.png}"/>
                                                </dx:SimpleButton.Content>

                                                <dx:SimpleButton.Style>
                                                    <Style TargetType="dx:SimpleButton">
                                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=VendorItemGrid,Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                                    </Style>
                                                </dx:SimpleButton.Style>
                                            </dx:SimpleButton>

                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </dxe:ComboBoxEdit.ItemTemplate>
                            </dxe:ComboBoxEdit>

                            <!--The VendorMainGrid Button-->
                            <dx:SimpleButton Grid.Column="1" Padding="0" Width="20" Height="20"
                                Name="MainButton"
                                Command="{Binding RowData.Row.AddVendorCommand}"
                                >
                                <dx:SimpleButton.Content>
                                    <Image Source="{dx:DXImage Image=Add_16x16.png}"/>
                                </dx:SimpleButton.Content>

                                <dx:SimpleButton.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="dx:SimpleButton">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=VendorMainGrid,
                                                   Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </dx:SimpleButton.Style>

                            </dx:SimpleButton>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
            </dxg:GridColumn>
        </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Could someone please point out why I am seeing this behavior, and how I need to change the DataTemplate so that I get the behavior I am looking for.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that the reason that the mouse-over doesn't work like I want it to is that I did not declare a background value for the parent grids. A control without any background by default has the Background property set to "null" which makes it impossible to hit test.

To solve this issue I just needed to declare Background="Transparent" on the parent grid controls, which will then allow the hit-test to work and detect the mouse-over.